# How do you implement an inline editable tag field with autocomplete that accepts new tags ?(rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, tags

I need to make an inline editable fields that also accept tags that are not on the table of the autocomplete just like stackoverflow.......I'm on rails 4....

For example, if I have a table of animals and this table has 'cat', 'dog', 'whale'

and then someone enters 'fox' I need to accept that tag as well and save it for future suggestions. Which is the best way to implement this? If I leave the tag system to open options I'm worried about bad words entering the database. How can I avoid this? With a black list of words for tags to validate in the model or something?......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [select2-rails](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails) gem, which allows you to integrate the Select2 jQuery plugin. Check out the [tagging support example](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags).

Comment: Thanks for the tool my friend. Regarding the matter of people entering bad words, how would you filter those? With a validator in the model?